# Remove sign out link from top link in magento 2.1 C E

Tags: magento2

I have added below given xml code in default.xml, sign out is coming two times , 1 is in dropdown and another one is in top links, i want to remove signout from top links in magento 2.1
please check the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="free_shipping">
            <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">free_shipping</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>            
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock  name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="storelocate.link" after="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Locator</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">store-locator</argument>
                        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">store_locator</argument>
                    </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="comcom.link" after="about-us">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Community Commerce</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">community-commerce</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">community_commerece</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="story.link" after="comunity-commerce">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Our Story</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">our-story</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">our_story</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="ingred.link" after="our-story">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Our Ingredients</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">our-ingredients</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">our_ingredients</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>         
            <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- <referenceContainer name="header.panel">                
            <container name="header-links-nxt" as="header links" label="Header links" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="header links secondary" after="-">

            </container>
        </referenceContainer> -->


        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer-content-customised" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-content-customised" before="-">
                <container name="footer-top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-top page-main sheamoisture_footer_contents" before="-">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-content-top">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-content-top</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="footer-bottom" as="footer content" label="Footer Bottom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content" after="-">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="FAQ">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Privacy Policy">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy Policy</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Terms of Use">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Terms of Use</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">terms-of-use</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Returns Policy">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Return Policy</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">return-policy</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>            
                </referenceBlock>
            </container>            
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="footer-bottom" destination="footer-content-customised" />

<!-- <move element="minicart" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header.links" after="-"/> -->

        <move element="catalog-search-advanced-link" destination="footer_links" before="-"/>
        <referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="points.balance" remove="true"/>


        <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="sales-guest-form-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="footer-bottom"/>
        <referenceBlock name="contact-us-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep below code inside your themes **default.xml** file,

After keep below code, Sign in and Sign out link are remove from top links.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>    
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true"/>
         </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: actually sign in link i want in top links, once customer sign in,  signout is coming in drop down and in out side of dropdown its in top links header. i have to remove another one which is coming  outside of dropdown.

Comment: plz share your screenshot

Comment: am unable to share screenshot. can u please register in this given link and check please.  http://dev.i3lsundial.com/

Comment: You can try with, <referenceBlock  name="header.links">
     <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true"/>
</referenceBlock> in default.xml file

Comment: plz let me know after check

Comment: i think using this sign in and sign out both link will remove know..?

Comment: its unable to remove signout link ..

Answer (score 4):

In default.xml write this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>    
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true"/>
     </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Which removes the signin link too.

Answer (score 1):

Override Authorization.link block file from vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account to your module and change from:
`

```
public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In');
    }
```

to

```
public function getLabel()
{
    return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('') : __('Sign In');
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This suggestion didn't answer correctly the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the authorization link but that would also remove the sign in link.

Another way to go about this is to use something like this https://github.com/TheFrankman/magento2-customhandles to add the customer_logged_in and customer_logged_out handles to Magento 2

Then create a customer_logged_in.xml with the removal of the authorization-link-login (removing authorization-link would also remove the account icon dropdown)